# Changing shell to zsh broke my terminal

Tags: 11.04, bash, gnome-terminal, zsh

I ran `sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh` to change my default shell to zsh. I then restarted my computer. When I turned it back on I get just `$` as the prompt, so it doesn't look like I even get bash any more.

```
echo $SHELL is "/bin/sh"
```

Next steps to either return my shell to bash or fix zsh? This is for Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't make a typo and run `chsh -s /bin/sh`? And note that `sudo chsh` changes root's shell, which isn't a good idea; is this what you really wanted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- zsh is not installed by default. Did you install it?
- Are you able to start zsh manually by typing

  ```
  /bin/zsh
  ```

  at the prompt?

If you answerded both with yes, I suggest you have a look into /etc/passwd. In the first line it should say

```
root:x:0:0:root:/bin/zsh
```

If that's not the case, you may also set it here instead of doing it via chsh. 
**But make sure you really installed zsh and you enter the path correctly or you might find yourself locked out of your system.**